# Pandas long to wide with hierarchical column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've looked up and down but can't find an example that closely resembles what I'm trying to do. In short, I have multiple trials of an experiment with multiple variables. The data is collected and stored in a long dataframe object, like so (generated data example):

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from scipy import rand

trials = ['trial_1' , 'trial_2']
ppi = ['5_ppi', '10_ppi']
rd = ['7%', '12%']
iter = [rd, ppi, trials]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for k, params in enumerate(list(itertools.product(*iter))):
    ext_data = [rand(), rand()]
    load_data = [rand(), rand()]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ext': ext_data, 'load': load_data, 'trial': params[2], 'ppi': params[1], 'rd': params[0]})
    df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=0)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
df
        ext      load    trial     ppi   rd
0  0.287997  0.874457  trial_1   5_ppi   7%
1  0.783776  0.878291  trial_1   5_ppi   7%
0  0.015054  0.886801  trial_2   5_ppi   7%
1  0.243617  0.234560  trial_2   5_ppi   7%
0  0.291621  0.519084  trial_1  10_ppi   7%
1  0.627786  0.072551  trial_1  10_ppi   7%
0  0.349199  0.235718  trial_2  10_ppi   7%
1  0.284535  0.328547  trial_2  10_ppi   7%
0  0.725747  0.688157  trial_1   5_ppi  12%
1  0.656839  0.297645  trial_1   5_ppi  12%
0  0.534276  0.794199  trial_2   5_ppi  12%
1  0.680596  0.381575  trial_2   5_ppi  12%
0  0.494404  0.246841  trial_1  10_ppi  12%
1  0.148489  0.549250  trial_1  10_ppi  12%
0  0.791440  0.372119  trial_2  10_ppi  12%
1  0.078047  0.552541  trial_2  10_ppi  12%

[16 rows x 5 columns]
```

(in reality there are hundreds of data points for each trial, not just two like shown here)

I would like to convert this to a wide dataframe with hierarchical columns, organized like so (i can't use markdown to make values/headers span multiple columns, so please forgive the screenshot)

[image]

I've tried so many things that I've lost track. I think `pivot_table` got me the closest to what I want, but it winds up aggregating the mean of the values instead of listing them out, like so:

**Input:**

```
df.pivot_table(columns=['rd', 'ppi', 'trial'])
```

**Output:**

```
rd          12%                                      7%                             
ppi      10_ppi               5_ppi              10_ppi              5_ppi          
trial   trial_1   trial_2   trial_1   trial_2   trial_1  trial_2   trial_1   trial_2
ext    0.619217  0.661812  0.652555  0.167241  0.340024  0.42324  0.565166  0.436858
load   0.397430  0.102965  0.528162  0.550871  0.206560  0.28524  0.731204  0.303079

[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

It is also possible that each set of data has a different number of data points (i.e. Trial 1 might contain 2 data points, while Trial 2 might have 3). I'm at my wits end. What is the magic command to turn this long dataframe object into a wide dataframe object with multiple hierarchical columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
idx_cols = [*df][-1:-4:-1]
res = df.set_index(idx_cols + [df.groupby(idx_cols).cumcount()])
res = res.stack().unstack([0,1,2,-1])
print(res)
```

[image]

Comment: This is super elegant, but rather esoteric given my comparatively limited experience with Python. I eventually got it to work on my own by restructuring the original data to be even "taller" than before, but your solution looks a lot simpler. I'm not sure I understand how it works, though.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient answer, but I think it is achieving your desired outcome and should work for any number of observations.

```
def reformat(df, column_name):
  groups = df.groupby(['rd','ppi','trial'])[column_name].apply(list)
  temp_1 = groups.reset_index(name = 'listvalues')


  # Make names for each of your new columns
  col_names = [column_name + str(i) for i in np.arange(len(temp_1['listvalues'][0]))]
  # Split listvalues into df where every item is its own column
  listvalues = pd.DataFrame(temp_1["listvalues"].to_list(), columns=[col_names])

  # Merge listvalues with the temp_1 df and get rid of the extra listvalues column
  df = temp_1.join(listvalues)
  del df['listvalues']

  df = df.pivot_table(columns=['rd', 'ppi', 'trial'])
  return df

# Do this twice and append to get the desired dataframe
df2 = reformat(df, 'ext')
df3 = reformat(df, 'load')
finaldf = df2.append(df3)
```

Where finaldf looks like:

[image]

Comment: It's close, but I would have liked to have "ext0" and "load0" be their own columns that fall under each "trial". @ziying35's answer looks like it puts it in the format I'm looking for, but I'm having trouble understanding how his code works.

I also managed to get a version of it working on my own by recasting the original data to be even "taller" than shown in the original post. Basically, all the data (both "ext" and "load") gets put into one single column, and then labeled in the next column as either "ext" data or "load" data, then the rest of the data labels are included as well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution that is probably the more "correct" way of doing it, but it required me to rearrange my *original* data set so that the `.pivot()` method would work correctly. Here's how I re-cast the data:

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from scipy import rand

trials = ['trial_1' , 'trial_2']
ppi = ['5_ppi', '10_ppi']
rd = ['7%', '12%']
iter = [rd, ppi, trials]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for k, params in enumerate(list(itertools.product(*iter))):
    ext_data = [rand(), rand()]
    load_data = [rand(), rand()]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data': ext_data, 'type': 'ext', 'trial': params[2], 'ppi': params[1], 'rd': params[0]})
    df2 = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame({'data': load_data, 'type': 'load', 'trial': params[2], 'ppi': params[1], 'rd': params[0]})])
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
df
       data  type    trial     ppi   rd
0  0.959315   ext  trial_1   5_ppi   7%
1  0.394340   ext  trial_1   5_ppi   7%
0  0.140045  load  trial_1   5_ppi   7%
1  0.519967  load  trial_1   5_ppi   7%
0  0.483302   ext  trial_2   5_ppi   7%
1  0.552380   ext  trial_2   5_ppi   7%
0  0.907199  load  trial_2   5_ppi   7%
1  0.123719  load  trial_2   5_ppi   7%
0  0.190914   ext  trial_1  10_ppi   7%
1  0.053163   ext  trial_1  10_ppi   7%
0  0.085914  load  trial_1  10_ppi   7%
1  0.749197  load  trial_1  10_ppi   7%
0  0.112615   ext  trial_2  10_ppi   7%
1  0.363111   ext  trial_2  10_ppi   7%
0  0.508180  load  trial_2  10_ppi   7%
1  0.459821  load  trial_2  10_ppi   7%
0  0.346808   ext  trial_1   5_ppi  12%
1  0.322950   ext  trial_1   5_ppi  12%
0  0.642119  load  trial_1   5_ppi  12%
1  0.101987  load  trial_1   5_ppi  12%
0  0.488866   ext  trial_2   5_ppi  12%
1  0.583071   ext  trial_2   5_ppi  12%
0  0.119333  load  trial_2   5_ppi  12%
1  0.800356  load  trial_2   5_ppi  12%
0  0.733883   ext  trial_1  10_ppi  12%
1  0.856037   ext  trial_1  10_ppi  12%
0  0.980035  load  trial_1  10_ppi  12%
1  0.364698  load  trial_1  10_ppi  12%
0  0.697155   ext  trial_2  10_ppi  12%
1  0.712375   ext  trial_2  10_ppi  12%
0  0.285191  load  trial_2  10_ppi  12%
1  0.198097  load  trial_2  10_ppi  12%

[32 rows x 5 columns]
```

Then, with the data cast *entirely* long as shown above, I applied `.pivot()` to it like so:

**Input:**
`final_df = df.pivot(columns=['rd', 'ppi', 'trial', 'type'])`

**Output:**

```
final_df
           data                                                                                                                                                      
rd           7%                                                                             12%                                                                      
ppi       5_ppi                                  10_ppi                                   5_ppi                                  10_ppi                              
trial   trial_1             trial_2             trial_1             trial_2             trial_1             trial_2             trial_1             trial_2          
type        ext      load       ext      load       ext      load       ext      load       ext      load       ext      load       ext      load       ext      load
0      0.953832  0.012920  0.929764  0.069459  0.406110  0.866707  0.372693  0.815767  0.632988  0.310581  0.027626  0.416959  0.742982  0.340738  0.287946  0.294494
1      0.355673  0.663347  0.363117  0.860274  0.619436  0.146213  0.525354  0.038739  0.579613  0.488108  0.734074  0.794760  0.399273  0.517228  0.736619  0.860785

[2 rows x 16 columns]
```

Presto!